# C# Sort items in List<ArrayList> by DateTime

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

I have an list of arraylist `List<ArrayList> hallDetailsList` and i am trying to sort them by the time

List Data

```
hallDetailsList:
[0][0]Movie A|4:10pm|Hall 1
[0][1]Movie A |6:50pm|Hall 1
[0][2]Movie A |9:30pm|Hall 1
[0][3]Movie A |12:10am|Hall 1
[1][0]Movie B|4:40pm|Hall 2
[1][1]Movie B|9:40pm|Hall 2
[1][2]Movie B|12:10am|Hall 2
[1][3]Movie B|7:10pm|Hall 2
[1][4]Movie B|12:00pm|Hall 2
[1][5]Movie B|2:40pm|Hall 2
[1][6]Movie B|8:30pm|Hall 2
[2][0]Movie B|1:00pm|Hall 3
[2][1]Movie C|3:10pm|Hall 3
[2][2]Movie C|9:20pm|Hall 3
[2][3]Movie C|11:30pm|Hall 3
[2][4]Movie C|5:20pm|Hall 3
[2][5]Movie C|7:20pm|Hall 3
[3][0]Movie C|1:00pm|Hall 4
[3][1]Movie C|3:00pm|Hall 4
[3][2]Movie D|3:40pm|Hall 4
[3][3]Movie D|6:30pm|Hall 4
[3][4]Movie D|9:20pm|Hall 4
[3][5]Movie D|12:15am|Hall 4
[3][6]Movie D|5:30pm|Hall 4
[3][7]Movie D|12:30pm|Hall 4
```

I managed to sort the data through halls as previously they were just jumbled up everywhere. How do i sort the items now through time? as right now in some arraylist, the timing is messed up

Comment: FYI There is no datetime in your items, only time. Just saying...

Comment: yeah i converted the datetime to time. sorry i didnt state that

Comment: So, is this a array of objects or just an array of string

Comment: its a list of arraylists

Comment: Can you put the type in your question. ie `List<ArrayList> myAwesomeList` or what ever it is, as this is kind of confusing

Comment: Something like this? `hallDetailsList[0].Sort( (x,y) => DateTime.Compare(x.Split('|')[1], y.Split('|')[1] ) )` only problem is you need to convert the time strings back into DateTime to use `DateTime.Compare`

Comment: @Minijack, getting error `cannot convert lambda expression to type icomparer because it is not a delegate type`. Am i suppose to instantiate a custom iComparer first?

Comment: Enumerable.OrderBy is probably what @Minijack was going for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx

It does take a Func<,> as an argument.

Comment: Thanks @moreON. Yes, it needs to be an IEnumerable. Not familiar with ArrayList - Why are you using them anyway? why not List<T>?

Comment: Why are you using a `List<ArrayList>`? `List<>` is the generic replacement for `ArrayList`. If you want to be using `List<>` then you should probably use `List<List<object>>` as the modern equivalent of `List<ArrayList>`. Do you understand what I'm saying??

Answer (score 1):

**Given this**

```
List<ArrayList> hallDetailsList = new List<ArrayList>()
   {
      new ArrayList()
         {
            0,
            0,
            "Movie A",
            "1:10pm",
            "Hall 1"
         },
      new ArrayList()
         {
            0,
            0,
            "Movie A",
            "4:10pm",
            "Hall 1"
         },
      new ArrayList()
         {
            0,
            0,
            "Movie A",
            "3:10pm",
            "Hall 1"
         }

   };
```

**You can order like this**

```
var results = hallDetailsList.OrderBy(item => DateTime.ParseExact(((string)item[3]), "h:mmtt", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None))
                             .ToList();
```

**Or slightly more readable**

```
var Result= hallDetailsList.OrderBy(item =>
              {
                  var time = (string)item[3];
                  return DateTime.ParseExact(time, "h:mmtt", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
              }).ToList();
```

**Note** : Depending on your actual `ArrayList` you may have to change the indexing on

```
var time = (string)item[3];
```